# .ts stream stops after every few seconds

Tags: software-recommendation, video, streaming

I have a live .ts stream and I see that it is stopping after every few seconds in every player I have played.
As a work around, I have enabled the Repeat Track option in the players but still it is not the best solution because some of the stream is being skipped when the .ts stream is reopened.

What I all want is a player which can stream the .ts file without any interruption by caching it without the need of reopening the stream.
So that I don't need to enable the Repeat option.

I tried VLC, SMPlayer, MPV, MPlayer and even Kodi also. I would like to listen to solution which doesn't include Kodi (if possible).

Comment: This is probably due to the fact the the provider sending the .ts stream is lagging on their end. I use a IPTV service and have the same problem but have no problem streaming Netflix or Youtube. I use Perfect TV for Android but you can also get the PC Version.

Comment: Have you experimented with increasing the cache size? With vlc for example: Open Network Stream --> Show More Options --> Caching.

Comment: @andrew.46 Yes, but no use.